# Why does the jQuery source close before the rest of the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working through the book "Beginning Javascript". One of the examples in this book includes the following line:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
```

Why would I open and then immediately close the jQuery source? Doesn't it need to stay open to run the jQuery code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just including the jQuery library so you can use it. Your actual code would go in another script tag below it. Like this.

```
<div></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
$('div').text('Hello World!');
</script>
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks so much!